# Symfony2 Assetic can't load Ace Editor components

Tags: symfony, assetic, ace-editor

I'm trying to integrate [Ace Editor](http://ace.c9.io) into my Symfony2 app. But I'm facing problem which caused by Ace Editor dynamic component loader whenever it tries load Themes and Language supporter. In my template I simply load ace like this

```
{% javascripts 'bundles/app/js/ace/ace.js' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

then occurs: **Failed to load resource** error (theme or language js file).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you already tried [this bundle](https://github.com/norzechowicz/aceeditor-bundle)?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Matteo. I will take a look into it. Anyway, I don't think this issue is too complicated to install a bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
{% block external_javascripts %}
     <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/ace/ace.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I tried, and it was trying to load
http://myapp/web/mode-javascript.js 
http://myapp/web/theme-monokai.js 
which return 404 Not found error

Comment: Have you checked `\Symfony\src\your_bundle\Resources\public\app\js\ace\ace.js` ?

Comment: Actually I loaded ace.js with no problem. When I set theme for editor by editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai"); Ace would attempt loading theme-monokai.js file in its JS file. Then the problem occurred here when It tried to load in myapp/web/theme-monokai.js instead of its correct path must be myapp/web/bundles/app/js/ace/theme-monokai.js

Comment: there is no other way except modify the script who called it or place it in right place.